# Proving volume of a sphere

Tags: proof-verification, circles

I randomly decided to derive the volume of a sphere.

The area of a circle is $\pi r^2$.

So the volume, I thought, should be $\int \pi r^2 dr = \frac{\pi r^3}{3} $, summing up the area of many discs.

Shouldn't there be a $4$ in there? Why isn't there?

Comment: A factor $4$ applies to the surface area of a sphere.  Your approach to finding the volume is at best incomplete.  What are the limits of integration (needed for a definite integral)?

Comment: You can't just throw an integral in there and expect it to work out. First, can you explain (carefully) why you thought that integral would give you the enclosed volume of a sphere?

Comment: Try taking a spherical shell as the basic element instead of disks.

Comment: HInt. You can find this volume by summing disks, but you need to be careful The disks aren't all the same size, so $r$ isn't constant.

Comment: @EthanBolker That's why I was integrating over $r$

Comment: @Deepak I assumed that you can find the volume of something by summing up the areas of infinitely many discs. A sphere can be sliced up into many circles.

Comment: You need to work out just how $r$ varies. @GregordeCillia 's answer does that correctly.

Comment: Why can't I use a general integral without bounds

Comment: Hint 1: if you stack a bunch of disks you can get a cone.  Or if you stack a bunch of disks you can get a sphere.  Whats the difference?

Comment: "A sphere can be sliced up into many circles" so can a cone.  Or a cylinder.  Or a ...

Comment: @fleablood Ah, that makes a lot of sense now

Comment: You need to relate r to the height.  If you assume r = height then you get a cone.  If you assume r is constant you get a cylinder.  If you assume r = h^2 you get a trumpet.  If you assume r = sin(h) you get a christmas ornament.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you tried to apply actually works like this:
$$
V = \int_{-r}^r \pi y^2\ dx\qquad (1)
$$
where $x^2+y^2=r^2$. Plugging the Pythagorean identity in $(1)$ gives
$$
V = \int_{-r}^r \pi (r^2-x^2)\ dx = \pi\left[r^2x-\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{x=-r}^r=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3
$$
For more details see [this derivation](http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/derivation-formulas/derivation-formula-volume-sphere-integration).

Answer (score 0):

The missing $4$ actually comes from the area of spherical shell with radius $r$.

Let $(x,y)=r(\cos t, \sin t)$.  Then $(\dot{x},\dot{y})=r(-\sin t, \cos t)$.

\begin{align*}
  S &= \int_{-r}^{r} 2\pi y\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}} dx \\
    &= 2\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} y\sqrt{\dot{x}^{2}+\dot{y}^{2}} dt \\
    &= 2\pi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} r^{2} \sin t \, dt \\
    &= 4\pi r^{2} \\
  V &= \int_{0}^{R} 4\pi r^{2} \, dr \\
    &= \frac{4}{3} \pi R^{2}
\end{align*}